# interpreting logistic regression coefficients when reversing the reference group

Tags: logistic, interpretation, regression-coefficients

I applied logistic regression to check the relationship between a binary variable that is called FG and few independent variables

the reference group for the variable SSE is **SSE1**. The OR is 0.48 meaning that the chances for those in SSE2 (from the same age group and the same physiological status) decrease by 52% to be in FG group 1 compared to those from SSE1.

However now when considering SSE2 as the reference group :

now OR for SSE1 is 2.08 meaning the chances for SSE1 are 108% higher to be in FG group 1 compared to those from SSE2. Is it logical this way or am I making some interpretation error (because I thought that the resulted OR must indicate 52% more of chances) ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend that you don't try to interpret such results in terms of percentage changes. That too often leads to confusion like this. See [Frank Harrell post](https://www.fharrell.com/post/percent/) on "Why I Don't Like Percents."

If you just stay in the odds ratio (OR) scale, everything makes sense. The OR for `SSE2` versus `SSE1` is 0.48 in the first model. The OR for `SSE1` versus `SSE2` in the second model is exactly the inverse, 1/0.48 = 2.08, as expected. The problems arise when you try to convert to percentage changes as the baseline for comparison changes. There's no need to do that. As Harrell says:

> Many quantities reported in the scientific literature are naturally ratios. For example, odds ratios and hazard ratios are commonly used. If the ratio of stroke hazard rates [in] treatment B compared to treatment A is 0.75, I prefer to report “the B:A stroke hazard ratio was 0.75.” There’s no need to say that there was a 25% reduction in stroke hazard rate.

Comment: Thank you so much it was very helpful